# [Solved]IntelliJ IDEA cannot resolve symbol "c:out" when using JSTL 3.0

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

It seems that JetBrains fix this IDEA bug in IDEA 2023.1. If someone else have exactly same problem, check your IDEA version and update to 2023.1 or above. It may help.

---

Sorry for my poor English.

I am learning jsp. But my Intellij IDEA cannot resolve symbol "c:out" when I write on a JSP page. I want to use JSTL 3.0.

I add `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="jakarta.tags.core" %>` but it don't work.

I have dependencies in build.gradle:

```
implementation 'jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api:3.0.0'
implementation 'org.glassfish.web:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl:3.0.0'
```

I try to use `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` and it works well. But it is JSTL 1.2.

This is the jsp page.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="jakarta.tags.core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSP in Springboot 3!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello <c:out value="${msg}"/></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2022.3.1. I think it is a bug in IDEA. But I'm not sure whether I did something wrong.

Comment: that's crazy that 2023 some companies still use JSTL

Answer (score 0):

The new namespace introduced in JSTL 3 is not yet supported in the IDE. Feel free to upvote/comment for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-308542